# Posting from a Form in Partial View - Why is it triggering the wrong controller action?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

Bear with me as I describe the issue.

An MVC3 application making use of partial views. Having trouble posting a Comments form in a partial view from its parent-model's Details view.

For reference `ArticleViewModel` has a collection of `CommentsViewModel` so there is a OTM relationship.

#### Details View

```
@model ArticleViewModel

// Renders the Article and its Comments - no forms, just display markup
// A nested _Comments partial is used to render the article's comments.
@Html.Partial("_Article", Model)

// Renders HTML and Javascript for the Pagedown editor - POST form inside.
@Html.Partial("_CommentEditor", new CommentViewModel())

@section scripts { /* code here for validation and the javascript editor */ }
```

#### _CommentEditor Partial View

```
@model CommentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment","Article",FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />    
}
```

#### Article Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string slug) {
    return View(_articleService.Get(slug));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(string slug, CommentViewModel comment) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        _articleService.AddComment(comment, slug);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Slug = slug });
}
```

#### Scenario / Issue

1. Http Request for `/Article/Details/{slug}` renders the article, its comments, and the editor form correctly.
2. The editor works as intended, but on clicking Submit, I noticed the Details action on my controller being called rather than the HttpPost Comment action.

As you can see the Razor Form helper specifies the `Comment` action on the `Article` controller using `POST`.

#### Question

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chump Award!

**The answer is Routing.**

Looking closer with Fiddler, I was actually sending a `POST` request to `/article/comment`, so I checked my routing... how I missed this, I don't know:

```
routes.MapRoute("Article-Create", "article/create", new { controller = "Article", action = "Create" });
routes.MapRoute("Article-Edit", "article/edit/{slug}", new { controller = "Article", action = "Edit" });
routes.MapRoute("Article-Delete", "article/delete/{slug}", new { controller = "Article", action = "Delete" });
routes.MapRoute("Article", "article/{slug}", new { controller = "Article", action = "Details" });
routes.MapRoute("Articles", "articles", new { controller = "Article", action = "Index" });
```

There is no explicit route for the Comment action. There *is* a catch-all REST-ish route for fetching an article (`article/{slug}`). So the Comment POST was being handled by it before hitting the default route...

My specific solution (i like explicit routing - even when it gets me in trouble) was to add a route for comments, just about the catch-all `article/{slug}` pattern:

```
routes.MapRoute("Article-Comment", "article/comment", new { controller = "Article", action = "Comment" });
```

Problem solved. Embarrassing.